# Colorize AO layer shadows using Blender compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, ambient-occlusion

When compositing AO I use to colorize its shadows a bit bluish but not sure how to do it (or even if it's possible to do that)in Blender compositor. Any idea?

Comment: Hi :). Sure, just run the *AO pass* through a *Mix node* before you comp it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the *AO pass* through a *Mix Node* before you comp it in.

[image]

Comment: So easy. Thanks! I've been playing with color blending and I didn't realize screen was so evident to use